# How to pause ffmpeg in Java

Tags: java, ffmpeg, process

I have ffmpeg running as a process in Java.  I want to be able to pause it and be able to resume it later. I can make it quit, but cannot find a way to pause.

```
 Process ffmpeg = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ffmpeg_command, null);
                           
                                stderr = ffmpeg.getErrorStream();
                                stdout = ffmpeg.getOutputStream();
                                stdout.write("\r\n".getBytes());    
       

                                error_isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
                                error_reader = new BufferedReader(error_isr);
                           //     input_isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
                           //     input_reader = new BufferedReader(input_isr);
                              //  input_reader = new BufferedReader(input_isr);
                              //  int ch;

                                while (!error_reader.ready()) {
                                }
                                while ((errorstr = error_reader.readLine()) != null) {
                             
                                        if(stopconv =="yes"){  
                                        PrintStream ffmpegIn = new PrintStream(stdout);
// this successfully quits              ffmpegIn.println("q\r\n");
// ffmpeg by sending "q" to it          ffmpegIn.println("\n");
                                        ffmpegIn.flush();   
                                         
                                        if(pauseconv =="yes"){ 
                          // To pause the code needs to be here but how?
                                            pauseconv = "no";
                                                             }
```

the "pause" keystroke (Windows) works if just using ffmpeg in a command line, and I have been trying to replicate that without success. The code is just the relevant part.

Comment: You could possibly do it in a Unix based OS, but I'm guessing you're on Windows..?

Comment: Yes Windows I'm afraid. I can pause it by Thread.sleep(Very large number) but no way to resume it.

Comment: What is 'ffmpeg_command'? *if(stopconv =="yes")* That's not right btw. You have to compare strings with ```String.equals```. So, ```if("yes".equals(stopconv))```. Or better: ```if(YES.equals(stopconv))```  (constant) Also, prefer ```ProcessBuilder```

Comment: The easiest way that I can think of to control the data flow is to control the input stream. Read the source yourself and feed the data to `ffmpeg.getInputStream();`. To pause FFmpeg, simply pause the feed. FFmpeg process will patiently sit and wait for more inputs as long as its input stream is not closed.

Comment: That's what I was about to say @kesh ;) ffmpeg *will* read from a pipe so *if* you have an input stream to it, then you might do that. The only problem is possibly that you're using stdin to *control* it with commands: I doubt if you can do both

Comment: @g00se - not in Windows for sure :) (non-win32, you can use multiple named pipes)

Comment: Well it would *seem* that ffmpeg has to be explicit about pipes. I was thinking that something like ```type someaudio.ts | ffmpeg -f m4v out.mp3``` would work in Windows.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, I think using a pipe would probably work, however I have solved it by  using thread.suspend() and thread.resume(), they are depreciated but neverthess work, I am relatively new to java so it took a lot of time to work out how to get round the non-static method be referenced from a static context issue.